# 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Aqui está meu codigo

```js
var banco = "";
var clientes;

(async () => {
  clientes = await dbMysql.selectCustomers();
})();

  clientes.forEach(row => {
    if(row.Status == "Pendente" && row.Contadorinterno == 4){
      banco +=`\n\n ID: ${row.ID}\n Nome: ${row.Nome}\n Endereço ${row.Endereco}\n Motivo: ${row.Motivo}\n Status: ${row.Status}\n`;
    }
    else return ["Não existe nenhuma Manutenção no momento!"]
});


Codigo de conexão

async function connect()
{
if(global.connection && global.connection.state !== 'disconnected')
    return global.connection;
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");
const connection = await mysql.createConnection("mysql://root2:123@localhost:3306/cortes");
console.log("Conectou no MySQL!");
global.connection = connection;

return connection;
}

async function selectCustomers(){
const conn = await connect();
const [rows] = await conn.query("SELECT * FROM corte ORDER BY Endereco asc;");
return rows;
}
```

este é o erro que estou obtendo:

clientes.forEach(row => {
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8688/112052

Answer (score 0):

O seu clientes.forEach precisa estar dentro do async.

Ex:

```
(async () => {
  clientes = await dbMysql.selectCustomers();

  clientes.forEach(row => {
    if(row.Status == "Pendente" && row.Contadorinterno == 4){
      banco +=`\n\n ID: ${row.ID}\n Nome: ${row.Nome}\n Endereço ${row.Endereco}\n Motivo: ${row.Motivo}\n Status: ${row.Status}\n`;
    }
    else return ["Não existe nenhuma Manutenção no momento!"]
  });
})();
```

Comment: Funcinou, obrigado!